# Public vs Private IBOutlets

Tags: ios, oop, private, encapsulation, iboutlet

I wonder what is considered to be a better practice in a situation when I need to read the contents of the `UILabel` / `UITextField` from **another** view controller between the following two possibilities:

1) Simply create an `IBOutlet` to the `UITextField` in the .h file and make it public to everyone
2) Create an `NSString` **readonly** property in the .h file, make it readwrite in the implementation file, and update it every time the **private** `UITextField` changes.

In my opinion, the second option looks a better approach, because it maintains the OOP encapsulation, but it seems a lot of work to do with every `UITextField / UILabel` I have in every view controller.

Thoughts?
Thanks!

**EDIT:** In addition, if I need to have the ability to set the `IBOutlets` from outside, but in a `-(void)prepareForSegue:` method. So I guess the second option is the only option?

Answer (score 2):

Just create getter methods in the view controller for returning the required data. For example for `UITextField` :

```
- (NSString *)getTextFieldText {
   return self.myTextField.text;
}
```

No need to add a redundant property (NSString *) this way. 
As with encapsulation you are hiding the private data (i.e your IBOutlets) and expose only the data that is required by others

Comment: So I have to create a getter method in the header file for every IBOutlet I declare in the implementation file?

Comment: As with any other data you want an access to. You just don't expose the entire outlet

Comment: And what if in addition I need the ability to set it from outside? Do I have then to create a setter method for every IBOutlet?

Comment: Well if you need to get and set then maybe your first approach will be the easiest one but any other way you'll to have a getter/setter for each data you want to expose and change outside

Comment: Ok, thanks! BTW, I read somewhere that it is not a good practice to add "get" before a method name. Maybe simply name it -textFieldText?

Comment: Also, I cannot set the IBOutlets in the -prepareForSegue method, so I guess I need to have public properties anyway?

Comment: I put it for clarification as objc method convention is indeed a bit different but do whatever works for you best (unless its really off and confuses your team ;)).

Comment: @AnatolyAnatoly Correct.  If you're using storyboards, the outlets to the UIKit objects won't do anything (because `prepareForSegue:` is called before `awakeFromNib`, which is when the outlets first become available to you.)